# fail2ban regex failing to work

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I am trying to create a regex for my fail2ban filter to block all IPs that get a incorrect login on a web application. The way I distinguish this is that each login generates a GET request in the access log with this thing "?&err=1".

This is an example log line from the Apache access log:

```
XX.XX.XX.XX - - [14/Mar/2023:00:51:56 +0200] "GET /index.html?&err=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 37613
```

I tried this as regexes:

```
[[]client <HOST>[]] - - "?&err=1"
```

and

```
client <HOST> - - * "GET * err=1 *
```

but they don't block anything. What would be the correct regex here?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Update as of 19/04/2023:

I edited my web application to print following error line in error_log:
[Wed Apr 19 00:40:10 2023] [error] [client 8.8.8.8] Selecting user ERROR!, referer: https://example.net/

Following fail2ban regexes don't work:

```
1. failregex = ^\[client <HOST>\] Selecting user ERROR! 

2. failregex =  ^\[client <HOST>\] Selecting user ERROR!, referer: 

3. failregex = ^\[\w{3} \w{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{4}\] \[error\] \[client <HOST>\] Selecting user ERROR!, referer: https:\/\/example\.net\/
```

Any ideas where I am wrong?

Comment: Use code blocks to format code

Comment: These doesn't look like correct regexps. You probably want to test them with something like https://regex101.com/ and then with `fail2ban-regex`